# Headless chrome and qt

Tags: qt, headless-browser, qtwebengine

I am trying to pull xhr requests from headless crome  and get a responsebody. This can be done by Fiddler, but I want to do without him. Any ideas how to use qt to connect to headless crome and get a responsebody from every request from there? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by pull xhr requests? Evaluate them inside the page?

Comment: Some webpages get javascript from server and run it. It generates requests to server for periodic updates and get response as json. I want use this json in my project. I wrote script for Fiddler, that send JSON to my programm, but i want do this without him.